# 2 tcpdumps from a remote host

Tags: linux, shell, tcpdump

I need to collect tcpdump from different interfaces from a remote host.
Currently I do it in the following way:

> ```
> ssh remotehost "tcpdump -i iface1 -w - " > iface1_dump.pcap &
> ssh remotehost "tcpdump -i iface2 -w - " > iface2_dump.pcap
> ```

I wonder if there a way to realize it in single ssh connect (maybe some complex shell redirect is a cure) to minimize packets loss while second ssh command is on its way
2 conditions:
remote host has really limited disk space, so I can't tcpdump locally on that host
**tcpdump -i any** affects Ethernet headers, so I can't use it

Answer (score 0):

You create a file "SEND_DATA" on the target machine, in which you put these 2 lines:

```
tcpdump -i iface1 -w - | nc <IP> <PORT1>
tcpdump -i iface2 -w - | nc <IP> <PORT2>
```

Every machine has netcat, so it works. You mark SEND_DATA executable

Next, you open a listening port on your PC, and run the script on remote machine:

```
> OUT1 nc -l -p PORT1
> OUT2 nc -l -p PORT1
ssh remotehost SEND_DATA
```

In this moment, the files OUT1 & OUT2 will start receiving data.

You also need to consult the manuals from 2 versions of nc, because I saw that the parameters differ sometimes.

Comment: You woudln't believe, but that host doesn't have nc/netcat installed.
This is pretty specific server, running very specific WindRiver Linux distro

Comment: Then you must install netcat, some ssh client, some ftp client, etc. Otherwise, you can put the 2 commands into a scrit file, and configure tcpdump to output something differently on the same console, and then split the merged outputs on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

The two ssh's is probably the nicest method, but you could also sed 's/^/one /' on the first one, in the background, and sed 's/&/two /' on the second, and then pull them apart on the local host with "egrep '^one ' | sed 's/one //'" for example.

You could also save the output in a pair of files, and scp them back when "done".

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh remotehost "tcpdump -iiface1 -w- &
                tcpdump -iiface2 -w- >&2 2>/dev/null" >iface1_dump.pcap 2>iface2_dump.pcap
```